# How do I preserve file paths after cloning a failing external drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a failing external drive with Mac backups as well as my iTunes library, Photos library, and other application files. I purchased a replacement drive recently and am ready to clone the files over to the new drive.

How do I make sure that, after cloning the drive, my applications will read their files from the new drive without me manually having to re-specify the file locations? I.E. not having to manually update the file locations of every song in my iTunes library, or similar actions for other applications.

I'm assuming it's something simple like: making sure the name of the partition on the new drive is the same as the partition of the old drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *cloning* you mean you're going to use software such as [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) to create an exact image of your external drive, and as long as you ensure the external drive maintains the same volume name, then you should have no problems.

Once you've made the copy, however, I would no longer keep the other external drive connected.

**Libraries: iTunes and Photos**

In your question you state:

> How do I make sure that, after cloning the drive, my applications will
>   read their files from the new drive without me manually having to
>   re-specify the file locations? I.E. not having to manually update the
>   file locations of every song in my iTunes library.

Well, if you're only concerned about your Photos and iTunes library, then even if you didn't *clone* your external hard drive, you'd still be fine as you can manually set where the iTunes Library and Photos Library are located. This is a once off step. For example, once iTunes knows where it's *Library* is, it will find everything. **You don't need to manually update the file locations of *every* song in your iTunes library.**